# What is the correct syntax to changing the SQL command terminator using a remote connection by a JDBC driver?

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I use JDBC (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver v. 1.4.2) to connect to a DB2 database.

If I have to create a procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "Schema".makeUniqueCode(IN keyName VARCHAR(30),IN fieldName VARCHAR(30), IN tableName VARCHAR(30))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE COD VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE LASTCOD VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE at_end INT DEFAULT 0;
...
END%
```

I need to change the SQL command terminator from `;` to a new character ... I choose `%`.

If I put the create procedure command in a file.sql and use a DB2 CLI (db2 prompt), it is quite simple to change the SQL command terminator.

My problem is that I have to use a remote connection by a JDBC driver to execute the create procedure command.

What is the correct syntax to change the SQL command terminator using a remote connection by a JDBC driver?

Comment: Statements in JDBC should not have a terminator (but some drivers/databases allow it), you should only execute one statement in an `execute` (although some drivers do support multiple statements in one `execute`). A driver should (normally) consider a `CREATE .. BEGIN ... END` as one statement.

Answer (score 2):

The command terminator is a feature of programs that connect to the database, not the database itself.  The database is totally unaware of the existence of an SQL file, for example, that has multiple commands separated by a delimiter.  The SQL editor or client is where those are handled.

Now *you* are writing a program that connects to the database, so if you want to run multiple commands you have to manage that yourself.  JDBC and other database drivers give you an interface for executing single commands.  You just have to use that interface for each command you want to run.

If you do want to be able to execute a bunch of commands all at once with a single call from JDBC, put them in a stored procedure or use something like `BEGIN ATOMIC...END`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question has not really been answered yet because what Leonardo tries to do is perfectly valid: submitting a single DDL statement for CREATE PROCEDURE through JDBC that however includes a routine body with multiple statements inside the procedure.

You can take a look at the official DB2 samples how to submit this. It is for DDL for trigger, but this also applies to DDLs for routines:

[Source code sample "TbTrig.java"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/java_jdbc/s-TbTrig-java.html)